# How can I catch exceptions in any part of code and do something in R?

Tags: r, error-handling

I want to call an SMS API whenever a code throws an error.
To elaborate, we have a lot of cron jobs on our server and for maintenance I want to be aware when ever one of these codes breaks.

So I want to send my self a SMS whenever an error happens.

I can't use try catch because I don't know which part of code might cause error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you use `tryCatch`?  There's no limit to the amount of code that can be dropped as an expression in a try-catch.  Worst case, you can call source an entire script: `tryCatch(source("entire-workflow.R"), error = function(e) e)`.  You could also look into a logging package such as [logger](https://github.com/daroczig/logger) as a sligthly different approach.

Comment: Why can’t you wrap the whole of your r code for each cron job and then use `traceback` to identify where the error occurred?

Comment: @cmhh Yes it works, however,This doesn't look like a best practice of clean code.

Comment: It certainly isn't something I've ever done, but that doesn't mean it's not _clean_.  At least it makes explicit in your code that you're doing such things... if that's important, of course.  Either way, I still wouldn't discount the value of a logging framework.I also often dump objects in my workspace out to disk at regular points in a long-running process so I can import them into a separate session and inspect them if things do go wrong, and so I can restart a process from where it crashed, rather than from the very start.

Comment: As the maintainer of `logger` and running thousands of batch jobs every day, I'm also suggesting implementing a logging framework, but for the sake of alerts, I'd also look for a job scheduler that can send notifications outside of the R -- e.g. Jenkins instead of `cron`, and set up plugins to send email/sms/pagerduty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably setting up a custom error handler. You can do that by setting option called `error`, which is `NULL` by default (unless you are using RStudio).

You can e.g. add such code to your `.Rprofile`:

```r
options(error = function() {
   your_function_to_send_sms(geterrmessage())
})
```

`geterrmessage()` is a function that accesses the last error message. You can check documentation of `options` and `geterrmessage` for details.

I personally haven't used that extensively, I've made a simple code once that dumps error to external file under some conditions.